# How to strongly adhere welcome mat to entry stairs without permanently damaging stairs?

Tags: adhesive

Two stairs from my garage are ~13" x 45"

Stairs appear to be granite or granite-like.

I want to cut a mat in half to put a half on each stair, but how can I secure it to the stairs so they don't slide off as I wipe my feet? Is there a strong glue that a solvent could completely remove later if the mat wears out, we move, etc.?

(For cleaning purposes, I might adhere a rug base or adhere one side of Velcro to adhere a washable rug to it.)

[image: stone stairs]

Comment: If it were me, I would just get some heavy rubber treads that are heavy enough where they won't slip, and no adhesive would be required. I think anything that you glue down will at minimum stain the granite when it's removed, even if you're able to remove the actual glue.

Comment: @LarryBud
1) Would you guess this staining issue would be true of silicone tape, as another has suggested?

2) Are you named after Larry "Bud" Melman?

Comment: Granite??? you should probably have them checked for asbestos.

Comment: Are your steps concrete?

Comment: Probably concrete? Just with a finish maybe IDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Bostik Blu Tack or similar "Tak" and "Tack" products made by Loctite and Scotch. No solvent needed to remove; you just roll it off with your finger. Any remaining residue can be removed by dabbing with another piece of the Blu Tack.

Comment: Thank you. The mats are sorta heavy so this might be the way to give just that extra security to keep them in place